# How to Read/Browse all my downloaded emails (.eml)?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, thunderbird

I'm coping with limited email space. I have downloaded emails using Thunderbird and I can open one email at a time, but I want to be able to open all emails from backup folder in my computer for browsing/searching. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the extension of your file from `".eml"` to `".mht"` and then can open in Internet Explorer. Other web-browser can also open MHT files but Internet explorer will format it correctly.

1) `Right-click` on the file name and Rename it 
2) Change `.eml` to `.mht`
3) Windows will warn you but try ignoring it.
4) Now right-click on the file and click on "`open with internet explorer`"

You will be able to view your files.

There is one more solution to open i.e you can simply right-click and open it in Notepad++ . Find "`html`" and "`body`" tag because it signifies the start of the mail. Find"`a href`" tags to find the links and you can easily copy and paste the url to view them.

Hope this will work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually I want to open/read/load all my downloaded emails so that I can sort/search and look for a particular email.

Comment: Try this method you can open your mails, read it and load.. And if still having issues then you can go for third party solutions as it is easily available online.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded all the emails to my local computer, through Mozilla Thunderbird. I have found a way around to search/browse through the downloaded emails. For example, i want to find an email with particular words in the "Subject". This is all done through windows explorer, where you can right click anywhere while in the emails folder and then select sort>more... and now check the boxes to display the relevant properties of the emails such as subject, date received, from etc. Now while in Emails folder, write *.* in search box. All emails will be enlisted with selected properties. It can easily be sorted, searched etc.